# Experience editor/Preview doesn't load Scripts. Sitecore 8.2

Tags: experience-editor, speak

When running any page in Experience Editor or Preview, Sitecore never finishes loading.

I've recently upgraded from Sitecore 7.2 to 8.2.

The `sc-progressindicator-inner` (which is visible in the image below) doesn't go away. And everything on the page is unclickable.

[image: loader]

I'm guessing that Sitecore doesn't finish loading it's scripts. I only get this error in the Console log:
[image]

I'm using Google Chrome, the old 7.2 version still works in the same browser.

Any ideas what prevents the scripts from loading?

I'm sorry I can't give more details but that's the problem, I have nothing else to go on myself.

Comment: Firstly; I would recommend clearing any and all browser caches for the site. It looks - to me - like you might be running some 7.2 javascript, possibly picked up from cache.

Comment: The other thing to check is MongoDB.  Many things simply don't work in Sitecore 7.5 and above if you don't have a connection to an instance of MongoDB and are not running in CMS-only mode.

Comment: I might also advise (especially since this was an upgrade)... deleting the sitecore/shell directory completely and copying the sitecore/shell directory from a vanilla install or from the root zip file that you can download.  Seems to me there might be some confusion going on.  There's also a slew of changes to the core database that setup the SPEAKUI for Sitecore 8.2  - Lastly, maybe attempt running the upgrade again using the Express Migration Tool?

Comment: I dont want to admit it. But I didn't find the error so I installed an empty 8.2 core dB and changed to it. It now works. Still no idea why though

Answer (score 0):

Firefox is the most stable browser for Sitecore Administration as suggested [here](https://books.google.mu/books?id=ZqIvCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA188&lpg=PA188&dq=sitecore%208%20chrome%20browser%20configuration&source=bl&ots=VlRdH7TuAG&sig=9PqjB0FWnbgaH4F9zwzt-NlkteE&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=sitecore%208%20chrome%20browser%20configuration&f=false). There are known issues that Google Chrome v37 and later does not work properly on Sitecore. This is due to the deprecated support for modal dialog boxes in these versions of Chrome.

I had experienced that the Experience Editor does not open or keeps on loading when using chrome. I have already logged a Sitecore Ticket for this and will update the answer once the information is provided

Comment: Google Chrome is [supported on all Sitecore versions 6.4+](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164). There was a [known bug for Chrome 37+ for which a fix is available](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/581527). I've not had any (major) issues with Chrome.

Comment: @jammykam yes but I think it may also due to the project which is using the experience editor. For example, the project I am working on is based mostly on JavaScript files which at some point in time cause issues on Chrome like the experience editor not opening, the popup of publishing is not opening

Comment: Sounds like a project specific issue rather than a Sitecore product specific issue... But without going into specifics, Sitecore functions fine on Chrome OOTB.